# Foreach loop problem in model using Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-3

Model:

```
public function fetch_emp()   
{ 
   $this->db->select('emp_id');
   $this->db->from('emp');
   $res=$this->db->get();
   foreach($res->result() as $row)
  {
      $id=$row->emp_id;
      $this->db->select('emp_name');
      $this->db->from('employee_master');
      $this->db->where('emp_id',$id);
      $res=$this->db->get();
      return $res->result();
   }
}
```

Controller:

```
public function employee()
{
  $result=$this->emp_model->fetch_emp();
  if($result!=false)
    $res['cmp_name']=$result;
  else
    $res['cmp_name']='NA';
}
  $this->loadViews("emp/emp_views", $this->global, $res , NULL);
}
```

View:

```
<?php print_r($cmp_name);?>
```

Once I fetch the id from db I got all the id not problem at all, but when I used in foreach loop to search the id and get their names from another db It display only the 1st id name...  For eg:If there are 5 id, but when I search the id to get the name from another db it shows the 1st id name only.What's the problem I don't know pls help me.

Answer (score 0):

You could get it done (getting names list) by directly using `join()` method like this :

```
public function fetch_emp() 
{ 
$this->db->select('emp_name');
$this->db->from('emp');
$this->db->join('employee_master', 'employee_master.emp_id = emp.emp_id');
$res=$this->db->get();
    return $res->result();
}
```

Comment: ya I am getting those datas but data are in array how can I convert into string??

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [emp_name] => ASK ) ) [1] => Array ( ) [2] => Array ( ) [3] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [emp_name] => sakur ) ) [4] => Array ( ) ) how can I retrieve those datas???

Comment: KK...I have another how to get empty array values to store in another array in php For eg. Array() I would like to store these values in another array, how can I do this??

Comment: You mean like : `$new_array[] = $old_array` ?

Comment: No.. Consider the array like   Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [emp_name] => ASK)) [1] => Array ( ) [2] => Array ( ). In this eg only array 0 contains the value so no problem values inserted in another array, but remaining 1 and 2 are empty array now how can I insert these data in another array.

Comment: I'm not really understand what your goal, how the array 1 and 2 getting empty? And you want to fill those empty arrays with what?

Comment: actually array 1 and 2 are empty in db so empty values  are display now I am store these value as null in another array.

Comment: Try removing the empty arrays using `array_filter()` function : `$array = array_filter(array_map('array_filter', $array));`